# How do programs like AutoHotkey prevent Windows Hotkeys?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm currently trying to override the default Windows hotkeys (like <kbd>Win + E</kbd> to open `explorer.exe`). I've tried many options, but nothing seems to work for me. I know this is possible, because both AutoHotkey and PowerTools can do it.

Also, I would like to avoid partial solutions, like disabling all Windows shortcuts in the Registry, mainly because it doesn't solve the problem, and hotkeys like <kbd>Win + Arrow</kbd> still isn't disabled or usable by `RegisterHotKey()`.

Comment: Search for windows global key hooks

Comment: Tomorrow i'll look into that aswell, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: How does open source project *X* do *Y*? Why not look into the [source code](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L)?

Comment: I've looked all this morning in the source of both project with little success (for sure for my little experience in c).. and maybe some one here can point me in the right direction

Comment: A `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD[_LL])` hook can intercept and discard keyboard presses.

Comment: It does [not use](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/dad681d19504bd24782b3f57552121a24e470e84/source/hook.cpp#L4349) RegisterHotKey().

Comment: You can know by looking at its source code that it uses [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) to achieve this function.